# F#: unable to use Suave.Types for build script

Tags: f#, suave

Trying to use Thomas Petriek's build script: https://github.com/tpetricek/suave-xplat-gettingstarted/blob/master/build.fsx

Getting error that the namespace Types is not defined in open Suave.Types.

Is this some namespace that has since been deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is an old version of the build script, but I am using the same build script myself, I had to make a couple of changes namely, remove the logging, use

```
open Suave.Http
```

instead of

```
open Suave.Types
```

and use these bindings

```
bindings = [ HttpBinding.create Protocol.HTTP Net.IPAddress.Loopback 8083us ]
```

Comment: Thanks can you post the full build script?

Comment: I'm getting an error that the create method is not defined. Do I have to include some other package? edit: I got it to work using HttpBinding.mk as a method. IDK if that's ok.

Comment: That's my build script, note, #load "app.fsx" won't run, but that is where my program is that I do load.